# ExtJS grid locking error post sencha build

Tags: extjs, grid, locking

When I use `enableLocking : true`, I get following error at the time of running the application -

On Browser:

```
TypeError: mixinClass is undefined
...lass.prototype, prototype = me.prototype, key, statics, i, ln, staticName, mixin...
```

When I try to debug:

```
mixin: function(name, mixinClass) {
var me = this, mixin = mixinClass.prototype, prototype = me.prototype, key, statics, i, ln, staticName, mixinValue, hookKey, hookFunction;
if (typeof mixin.onClassMixedIn != 'undefined')
{
mixin.onClassMixedIn.call(mixinClass, me);
}
```

This works perfectly on ext-dev OR ext-dev-all, but something wrong happens when Sencha Build executes and builds the consolidated app.js.

Please guide :)

EDIT: If possible please suggest me some JS classes I should add to requires[] in my application.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the missing class:

```
Ext.grid.locking.Lockable
```